Pandas dataframe group by column get count of two columns
I am pulling in data from an excel spreadsheet and creating a list of dictionary objects from the rows in that spreadsheet.  I converted that to a pandas dataframe.  In this data frame I have a column with unique names and then two more columns success and failed in these column I was keeping a count per so either 1 0.
Name   success   failed
Name1  1         0
Name1  0         1
Name1  1         0
Name1  0         1
Name1  1         0
Name2  1         0
Name2  1         0
Name2  0         1
Name3  1         0
Name3  0         1
Name3  0         1
Name3  1         0

I found using df.groupby("name").to_values() displays the name and success and failed column and the columns  are grouped with the totals per name of success and failed, but I do not know how to continue working with this as a new dataframe object.  If I output this to excel I just have one row with totals. Is there a way to create a new object from this with all my columns? My intention was to then show a percentage of a total from the two success and failed per name counts after that.
Name  Success
Name1 90%
Name2 94%
Name3 89%


Code
out = df.groupby('Name')['success'].mean().map('{:.1%}'.format).reset_index()

out:
    Name success
0  Name1   60.0%
1  Name2   66.7%
2  Name3   50.0%


Not sure if I have fully understand your question and output. It would be better if you give expected output to better understand.
But here is something you can do.
I assume you have already calculated the % of success.
You can simply do:
group_df = df.groupby('Name').sum().reset_index()
group_df['total'] = group_df['success'] + group_df['failed]

The output of the above code would be something like this:
Name Success Failed Total 
Name1  3       2     5

